# How do I send downloaded .mp3 with a Discord.js bot using ytdl-core?

Tags: javascript

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const fs = require("fs")
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core")

const config = require("./config.json")

fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  files.forEach(file => {
    let eventFunction = require(`./events/${file}`)
    let eventName = file.split(".")[0]
    client.on(eventName, (...args) => eventFunction.run(client, ...args))
  })
})

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return
  if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

  try {
    let commandFile = require(`./commands/${command}.js`)
    commandFile.run(client, message, args)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  if(command === "test"){
    let url = args[0]
    ytdl(url, {filter:'audioonly', format:'mp3'}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("audio.mp3"))
    message.channel.sendFile("./audio.mp3")
  }
});

client.login(config.token)
```

commands are stored in seperate files, but I write in the
    if(command === "test")
for testing commands

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Stream` and it's asynchronous. To make it work you need to check is the file's writing process completed or not!

```
ytdl(url, {filter: 'audioonly', format: 'mp3'})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('audio.mp3'))

// End of writing
.on('end', () => {
    message.sendFile('./audio.mp3');
});
```